# Specific sutta in the Tipitaka: Where did the Buddha compare leaves in the forest to his knowledge?

Tags: pali-canon, reference-request, tipitaka

I'm trying to find the sutta in where the Buddha is walking through a forest with his disciples. He then picks up a handful of leaves and says that what he teach is comparable to the leaves in his hand and what he did not teach is comparable to the amount of leaves in the forest.

Help would be much appreciated.

Lanka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably after the Simsapa Sutta
http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.031.than.html